# asp.net Website can't connect to SQL server - login error

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

out of the blue i am getting intermittent error from my website saying:

**A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)"}**

any suggestion on what might be wrong? seems like the connection to the db can't be established but i don't understand why it would be complaining about the login process

Comment: You might want to check that TCP/IP is enabled in `SQL Server Configuration Manager`

Comment: He said intermittent errors, how is your userid password setup..looks like there is some code somewhere (possibly hardcoded) that connects with a wrong user id and password..do you have a stack trace as to "where" in the code your this error occurs..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following and let me know if you find it useful.

1. Login with windows authentication.
2. Right click on the Instance name - Server Properties
3. Security page
4. Set the Server Authentication - 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode'
5. Restart the SQL Service.

Then close the sqlserver and restart. It should work.

if the above steps donot work then try thebelow ones:
Make sure the user is not disabled
1. Login as an Administrator into the SqL Server

1. Expand Security/ Logins folder
2. Right Click on the particular user and go to properties
3. Click Status Permission: Granted

Login : Enabled

SQL configuration wizard and make sured that TCP/IP and named pipes are enabled and that they are set to priorities 1 and 2.